# Continuous functions that satisfies $f(x) + f(1-x) + f(\sqrt{x^2+(1-x)}) = 0$ and $f(\frac12)=0$

Tags: calculus, functions, functional-equations

$f:[0,1]\rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ is a continuous function which satisfies
$$
f(x) + f(1-x) + f\left(\sqrt{x^2+(1-x)}\right) = 0 \text{ and } f\left(\tfrac12\right)=0.
$$

Can someone give explicit examples of $f$, apart from the trivial solution, $f(x)=0$? And are there infinitely many solutions for $f$?

I can derive some properties like $f(\frac{\sqrt3}2)=0$ or $f(0)=-2f(1)$, but I can't generate particular examples. Continuity seems important here, but I can't see how to use it, for if we take $f(x)=0$, for $x\in (0,1)$, and $f(1)=1$, $f(0)=-2$ also works.

Comment: Thanks @Goos. It must be late.

Comment: I sense some trigonometry here.

Comment: @Awesome Hmm. How?

Comment: I just get a feeling, you know? I see $1/2,\sqrt 3/2$ and the I see domain of the function...

Comment: Where does this problem come from?

Comment: @Awesome It almost works to plug in $x = \cos^2 \theta$.  But I don't know how to reduce $\sqrt{\cos^4 \theta + 1 - \cos^2 \theta}$.

Comment: @Goos Same here. Perhaps some other function...

Comment: @Goos If I'm not mistaken this in turn reduces to $\sqrt{1-cos^2(x)sin^2(x)}$. Then you can set cos^2 and sin^2 as two new variables,  but that leads nowhere.

Comment: Also to  $\frac{\sqrt{\cos (4x) +7}}{8}$

Comment: @GabrielR. But the two variables will be dependent.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

First, notice that $\sqrt{x^2+1-x}\geq\sqrt{3}/2$ for all $x\in[0,1]$. Let $g:[1/2,\sqrt{3}/2]\to\mathbb R$ be an arbitrary continuous function such that $g(1/2)=g(\sqrt{3}/2)=0$. Then, define $f:[0,1]\to\mathbb R$ as follows:
\begin{align*}
f(x)=\begin{cases}
0&\text{if $x\in[0,1-\sqrt{3}/2]$,}\\
-g(1-x)&\text{if $x\in(1-\sqrt{3}/2,1/2]$,}\\
g(x)&\text{if $x\in(1/2,\sqrt{3}/{2}]$,}\\
0&\text{if $x\in(\sqrt{3}/2,1]$.}
\end{cases}
\end{align*}

For example:

[image: Example:]

Comment: Fantastic answer!  Are there any other solutions?

Comment: Nice :) This also proves there are infinite solutions :)

Comment: @Goos I don't know if there exist other solutions, but as Sawarnik notes, it does provide infinitely many solutions. ;-)

Comment: @Sawarnik There are infinitely many infinitely differentiable solutions.

Comment: @Goos Indeed, you can take $g$ to be an arbitrary multiple of the translated and contracted version of the [bump function](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bump_function).

Comment: @triple_sec *any* bump function, not just *the* bump function.  Or multiple bump functions added together.

Comment: @Goos True that! I'm now wondering whether there exist solutions that do not vanish on $(\sqrt{3}/2,1]$. If they do, I guess they must be really badass.

Comment: @triple_sec There are other solutions; you can pick the values for $f$ essentially in the entire ranges $\left[1 - \frac{\sqrt{3}}{2} , \frac{\sqrt{3}}{2} \right]$
and $\left[ \frac{7}{4} - \frac{\sqrt{3}}{2} , 1 \right]$ but $f$ is then determined everywhere else.  I've made an answer about this, but it is quite gross.

Answer (score 1):

Here is the set of all possible $f$.
The algebra gets a little gross, so bear with me.

First, let 
$f_1: \left[1 - \frac{\sqrt{3}}{2}, 1 \right]
\to \mathbb{R}$ be an arbitrary continuous function such that $f_1(x) = 0$ on the closed interval $\left[ \frac{\sqrt{3}}{2}, \frac{7}{4} - \frac{\sqrt{3}}{2} \right]$,
and $f_1(\tfrac12) = 0$,
and finally,
$f_1(\tfrac{\sqrt{3}}{2}) + f_1(\frac{7}{4} - \frac{\sqrt{3}}{2}) = 0$.

Second, define
$f_2 : \left[1 - \frac{\sqrt{3}}{2}, 1 \right] \to \mathbb{R}$
by
$$
f_2(x) =
\begin{cases}
f_1(x)
& \text{if } 1 - \frac{\sqrt{3}}{2} \le x \le \frac{\sqrt{3}}{2} \\
- f_1\left( \frac{1 - \sqrt{4x^2 - 3}}{2} \right)
- f_1\left( \frac{1 + \sqrt{4x^2 - 3}}{2} \right)
& \text{if }
\frac{\sqrt{3}}{2} \le x \le \frac{7}{4} - \frac{\sqrt{3}}{2} \\
f_1(x)
& \text{if }
\frac{7}{4} - \frac{\sqrt{3}}{2} \le x \le 1 \\
\end{cases}
$$
Verify that
$f_2$ is continuous, and satisfies
$f_2(x) + f_2(1-x) + f_2(\sqrt{x^2 - x + 1}) = 0$
on its domain.
This is a bit gross, so I'm skipping the details for now.

Finally, define
$$
f_3(x) =
\begin{cases}
-f_2(1 - x) - f_2(\sqrt{x^2 - x + 1})
&\text{if } 0 \le x \le 1 - \frac{\sqrt{3}}{2} \\
f_2(x)
&\text{if } 1 - \frac{\sqrt{3}}{2} \le x \le 1 \\
\end{cases}
$$
Verify that $f_3$ is continuous,
and satisfies
$f_2(x) + f_2(1-x) + f_2(\sqrt{x^2 - x + 1}) = 0$
on its domain.
This is not too hard given that we already showed it for $f_2$.

Now just set $f = f_3$.

---

The end result is a function $f$
such that $f_1 = f$ on
$\left[1 - \frac{\sqrt{3}}{2}, \frac{\sqrt{3}}{2} \right]$
and $\left[ \frac{7}{4} - \frac{\sqrt{3}}{2}, 1 \right]$,
and $f$ satisfies the desired property.
So we get to choose $f$ however we want on
$\left[1 - \frac{\sqrt{3}}{2} , \frac{\sqrt{3}}{2} \right]$
and $\left[ \frac{7}{4} - \frac{\sqrt{3}}{2} , 1 \right]$,
and then $f$ is decided for us everywhere else.